# NET 6 asp net web controller how to use custom placeholder in the route template

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, url, controller, .net-6.0

Is it possible to have a custom placeholder in the controller route template, for a NET 6 asp net web server?

```
[Route("{myProjectApiName}/v{version:apiVersion}/testData")]
[ApiVersion("1.0")]
[ApiController]
public class MyTestController: ControllerBase
{
...
```

The "myProjectApiName" placeholder should be the string "api" by default, but it should be possible to set it to some project specific values, depending on some configuration parameter read at the startup of the application (for instance to some values like "myproj1-api", "myproj2-api",...).
The route URLs should also be displayed correctly in swagger:

```
...
app.UseSwagger();
app.UseSwaggerUI(c => c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "xxx.WebServer v1"));
...
```

How can this be achieved in NET 6?

Answer (score 0):

Just add the custom string into the header.

```
const string myString = "SomeRandomValue";
[Route("{myString}/[controller]")]
```

You should be able to put whatever you want inside the `[Route()]`

Comment: It is not allowed to add a variable in the RouteAttribute. The compiler generates the error "An attribute argument must be a constant expression, typeof expression or array creation expression of an attribute parameter type".

Comment: Sorry @RickyTad, corrected the code by adding const to the variable initialiser.

Comment: The compiler does not complaint, but I can write anything instead of "SomeRandomValue" in the url and the controller method is still reached. Practically it acts like a placeholder that can be filled with anything. And Swagger does not expand the url either, it shows something like "...{myString}/...". Where did you declare the const string, inside the controller class?

Comment: It works better like this [Route($"{myString}/[controller]")], but then it does not accept the version information added like this  [Route($"{myString}/v{version:apiVersion}/[controller]")]\n[ApiVersion("1.0")] . I need to dynamically set the string value from a json settings file, thus "const" is a problem (and "readonly" not accepted)...

Comment: This combination works indeed also with the versioning: [Route(myString+"/v{version:apiVersion}/[controller]")]\n[ApiVersion("1.0")] ! The only problem left is how to set dynamically the value of myString, as it must be a const variable...

Comment: If you use a helper class with the data you want copied into a `const` variable in there then create an instance of the class, does that work?

Comment: Unfortunately not, a const variable cannot be changed at runtime....

Comment: Maybe you can add multiple routes for the action.

Comment: Could you add some to the routes inside the controller class?